# I create a constructor CAR, but it means "c1.model();" doesn't return any value while calling the function

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function car(name,number)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
        this.model = function()
        {

            docoment.write("<h1>tata</h1>");
        }
    }
    var c1 = new car("hhb",215);
    var c2 = new car("jhg",98767);
    c1.model();
    document.write(c1.name);
</script>
```

I create a constructor CAR, but it means "c1.model();" doesn't return any value while calling the function.

Comment: `this.model = function()…` does not return any values. This is correct (you can notice lack of `return` statement). But what is your question?

Comment: docoment should be document IMHO

Answer (score 0):

Calling `document.write()` just writes the value into the web page, it doesn't return anything. You need a return statement.

```
this.model = function() {
    return '<h1>tata</h1>';
};
```

Also, see [Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)